# Navigator in react-native-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

```
 Navigation.setRoot({
      root: {
        stack: {
          children: [s
            {
              component: {
                name: `Danapay.${screen}`,
                passProps: {},
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    });
```

Through a TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'this.nativeCommandsModule.setRoot') in react native navigation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be caused by a typo in your code:

```js
       stack: {
          children: [s // <-- This should not be here
            {
              component: {
                name: `Danapay.${screen}`,
                passProps: {},
              },
            },
          ],
        },
```

Comment: Hey Rapssito, sorry I think added the s while typing the question. I still failed to make it work. thank you though.